# scanf returns EOF before last input is reached

Tags: c, input, scanf, eof

I am trying to collect numbers until EOF is reached, then convert the numbers to English.

```
$ ./dtoa
22 
twenty two
```

Here is part of the program:

```c
int num;
while(scanf("%d", &num) != EOF)
        to_string(num);
```

The problem is, when I enter the input, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for EOF the last number won't actually get printed:

```
$ ./dtoa
22 33 44(EOF) twenty two
 thirty three(EOF)
 forty four
```

I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for the last number to show up. How can I fix it so the full input will be inserted in the first EOF?

Comment: press ^D some more times . This is a property of the terminal (pressing it during a line means to flush input , not to close the stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually send "an EOF" (close the stream), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> must be pressed right after a newline.

Otherwise, the terminal is sending buffered characters (same as an <kbd>Enter</kbd> but without adding `\n`).

Comment: When I press enter after inserting input the program doesn't give me a chance to enter EOF, and submits the number instantly. so after it finishes the with the numbers the program dosent terminate, and waits for me to enter EOF.

Comment: @avivgood2 That is expected: first, you press `Enter` to send the input, which gets processed by a first `scanf`, then the program again waits for more input, and at that moment you press `Ctrl` `D` to terminate the stream, which makes the *second* `scanf` call return `EOF`.